# method to delete an element from two lists

Tags: java

There are 3 classes. House, Car and ItemList

CAR CLASS

```
public class Car
{
    private int id;
    private String colour;

    public Car(int id, String colour)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.colour = colour;
    }

    public String getColour() //accessor method
    {
        return colour;
    }

    public int getId() //accessor method
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) // mutator method
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setColour(String colour) // mutator method
    {
        this.colour = colour;
    }

}
```

HOUSE CLASS

```
public class House
{
    private int number;
    private String colour;

    public House(int number, String colour)
    {
        this.number = number;
        this.colour = colour;

    }

    public String getColour() //accessor method
    {
        return colour;
    }

    public int getNumber() //accesor
    {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) // mutator method
    {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public void setColour(String colour)
    {
         this.colour = colour;
    }

}
```

ITEMLIST CLASS

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class ItemList
{
    private ArrayList<Car> cars;
    private ArrayList<House> houses;

    public ItemList()
    {
        cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
        houses = new ArrayList<House>();
    }

    public void addCar(int id, String colour)
    {
        Car myCar = new Car(id,colour);
        cars.add(myCar);

        //cars.add(new Car(id,colour)); one-liner

    }
    public void addHouse(int number, String colour)
    {
        House myHouse = new House(number,colour);
        houses.add(myHouse);
    }
```

i'm trying to create a method to delete an item/element from both lists(Car and House) by entering a number and a colour (takes 2 arguments, int and String) - will search through the lists and if it finds an object with the matching integer and String value will remove the objects from the list.

i came up with this so far

```
public void deleteByItem(int value, String colour)
    {
        Car car = new Car(value,colour);
        House house = new House(value,colour);
        boolean bCar = searchCarByItem(car);
        boolean bHouse = searchHouseByItem(house);
        if (bCar)
        {
           cars.remove(car);

        }
        if (bHouse)
        {
            houses.remove(house);

        }

    }
```

Comment: What problem are you encountering?

Comment: May I ask why you'd like to delete a house and a car having the same id and color ... that does not really make sense to me. If it is a learning example it looks a bit odd and if it is something you are really using you might need to reconsider your data structure.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void deleteByItem(int value, String colour) {
    cars.removeIf(car -> car.getId() == value && Objects.equals(car.getColour(), colour));
    houses.removeIf(house -> house.getNumber() == value && Objects.equals(house.getColour(), colour));
}
```

Comment: `.removeIf` is redundant here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57939779/11342159 can be done this way ?

Comment: @SHIVANSHNARAYAN nope, see comment

Answer (score -3):

```java
public void deleteByItem(int value, String colour)
{
     for(Car car: cars) {
         if (car.getId() == value && car.getColour().equals(colour)) {
             cars.remove(car);
         }
     }

     for(House house: houses) {
         if (house.getNumber() == value && house.getColour().equals(colour)) {
             houses.remove(house);
         }
     }
}
```

you can simple loop thought the array lists till you find the one that matches and remove it from the array list. mine is implemented to remove all matches and not only the first one. so if you want to remove only the first one you just have to do the following modifications

```java
public void deleteByItem(int value, String colour)
{
     for(Car car: cars) {
         if (car.getId() == value && car.getColour().equals(colour)) {
             cars.remove(car);
             break;
         }
     }

     for(House house: houses) {
         if (house.getNumber() == value && house.getColour().equals(colour)) {
             houses.remove(house);
             break;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't removing elements within the for-each loop lead to `ConcurrentModificationException`?

Comment: that may be the case for looping though with indexes, but when you loop with iterable form that will not happen, so you're good!

Comment: Even if it would work, using a for-each loop here is bad programming practice ... you are searching for the element in the list, then java is searching again for your item in order to delete it. Thus, for removing plain iterators should be used - faster and safer!

Comment: @zzimick From [Java's ArrayList Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html): "if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException." It seems to me like this code wouldn't work, and when I test it myself I in fact do get a `ConcurrentModificationException`.